# Java - Flink sending empty object on kafka sink

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

On my flink script I have a stream that I'm getting from one kafka topic, manipulate it and sending it back to kafka using the sink.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(1);
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", servers_ip_list);
    p.setProperty("gropu.id", "Flink");

   
    FlinkKafkaConsumer<Event_N> kafkaData_N =
            new FlinkKafkaConsumer("CorID_0", new Ev_Des_Sch_N(), p);
    WatermarkStrategy<Event_N> wmStrategy =
            WatermarkStrategy
                    .<Event_N>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                    .withIdleness(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                    .withTimestampAssigner((Event, timestamp) -> {
                        return Event.get_Time();
                    });
    DataStream<Event_N> stream_N = env.addSource(
            kafkaData_N.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(wmStrategy));
```

The part above is working fine no problems at all, the part below instead is where I'm getting the issue.

```
    String ProducerTopic = "CorID_0_f1";

    DataStream<Stream_Blocker_Pojo.block> box_stream_p= stream_N
                .keyBy((Event_N CorrID) -> CorrID.get_CorrID())
                .map(new Stream_Blocker_Pojo());

    FlinkKafkaProducer<Stream_Blocker_Pojo.block> myProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(
                ProducerTopic,
                new ObjSerializationSchema(ProducerTopic),
                p,
                FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE); // fault-tolerance

     box_stream_p.addSink(myProducer);
```

No errors everything works fine, this is the Stream_Blocker_Pojo where I'm mapping a stream manipulating it and sending out a new one.(I have simplify my code, just keeping 4 variables and removing all the math and data processing).

```
public class Stream_Blocker_Pojo extends RichMapFunction<Event_N, Stream_Blocker_Pojo.block>
{

        public class block {
        public Double block_id;
        public Double block_var2 ;
        public Double block_var3;
        public Double block_var4;}
        
        private transient ValueState<block> state_a;
        
        @Override
        public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
            state_a = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("BoxState_a", block.class));
        }

        public block map(Event_N input) throws Exception {

        p1.Stream_Blocker_Pojo.block current_a = state_a.value();

            if (current_a == null) {
                current_a = new p1.Stream_Blocker_Pojo.block();
                current_a.block_id = 0.0;
                current_a.block_var2 = 0.0;
                current_a.block_var3 = 0.0;
                current_a.block_var4 = 0.0;}

        
            current_a.block_id = input.f_num_id;
            current_a.block_var2 = input.f_num_2;
            current_a.block_var3 = input.f_num_3;
            current_a.tblock_var4 = input.f_num_4;
          
            state_a.update(current_a);
            return new block();
        };   
    }
```

This is the implementation of the Kafka Serialization schema.

```
public class ObjSerializationSchema implements KafkaSerializationSchema<Stream_Blocker_Pojo.block>{

    private String topic;
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjSerializationSchema(String topic) {
        super();
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(Stream_Blocker_Pojo.block obj, Long timestamp) {
        byte[] b = null;
        if (mapper == null) {
            mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        }
        try {
            b= mapper.writeValueAsBytes(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

        }
        return new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>(topic, b);
    }

}
```

When I open the messages that i sent from my Flink script using kafka, I find that all the variables are "null"

CorrID  b'{"block_id":null,"block_var1":null,"block_var2":null,"block_var3":null,"block_var4":null}

It looks like I'm sending out an empty obj with no values. But I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong. I think that the problem could be into my implementation of the **Stream_Blocker_Pojo** or maybe into the **ObjSerializationSchema**,  Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two probable issues here:

1. Are You sure the variable You are passing of type `block` doesn't have null fields? You may want to debug that part to be sure.
2. The reason may also be in `ObjectMapper`, You should have getters and setters available for Your `block` otherwise Jackson may not be able to access them.

Comment: Could you pelase elaborate giving me some examples please? Thanks

Comment: First of all, try printing/logging  the input to  `Stream_Blocker_Pojo` `map()` function. The other thing is to add the methods such as `getBlockId` and `setBlockId` for all fields insidde the `block` class.

Comment: I found the problem, I was already printing the pojo so that point was okay. But i was not assigning the variables. Now all done was a basic Java error..Thanks!